# Shorthand for body background in css

Tags: jquery, css

I wonder how to use a shorthand for css background attributes.
I wanted to override the existing image using jquery but no luck.
I have something like below:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/bg-dark.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

Jquery:

```
 $('body')
     .css('background', 'assets/images/bg-white.jpg')
     .css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
     .css('background-position', 'center center');
     .css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
     .css('background-size', 'cover');
```

Comment: just remove ;(semicolon) from everyline and put it to the last. And also use url('path') rather than only path in first line

Comment: @AhmadAsjad, yeah! LOL I never noticed the `;` thanks mate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.css('background', 'assets/images/bg-white.jpg')` is wrong. You can't assign an arbitrary string to the CSS `background` (or `background-image`) property. You need to assign it a *url*:

```
.css('background', 'url(assets/images/bg-white.jpg)')
```

You're also misusing semicolons. They terminate entire statements, not individual lines. Your chained `.css` calls cannot each end in a semicolon, you need *one* semicolon at the end of the entire chain.

Comment: this. also note that apostrophes around the url string are optional. ``'url(assets/images/bg-white.jpg)'`` is equal to ``"url('assets/images/bg-white.jpg')"``

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image properties like this:

Just pass properties via jQuery's [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method like this:

```
$("p").css({"background": "url('link_of_image')", "width": "400px"});
```

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#img').css(
    {
      "background": "url('https://imge.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/773_3701590-1920x1080.jpg')",
      "width": "600px"
    }
  );
  
})
```

```css
#img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="img">
  
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah this is what I did at first but image won't load coz it lacks `url`.